# How to login under root in ubuntu-dektop on Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, python, login, guest-session

I am complete newbie to Ubuntu and Servers installation/tuning. But I faced with the necessity to get the VPN server for my python script.

I have chosen vultr.com as the provider and bought the VPN with different OSs available. Among them, I have chosen Ubuntu 14.04 since it is free of charge compared to Windows OS.

In Ubuntu, I had the terminal only. I googled how to install desktop and found out that it easily may be done by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But, what I got was only a guest session available (please take a look at the picture attached)

[image: login screen to Ubuntu server]

I am not get used to work with command line OR terminal. I would like to have a GUI based system. In addition, my script uses Chromedriver (selenium etc.). I don't really know if it is possible to use Chromedriver under terminal only.

Please, help me to find the way to tune the Ubuntu server such that I could login under root or at least to create a user with admin permissions.

Comment: Have you got sudo privileges/root password?

Comment: yes, I have sudo preferences if I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 I see terminal and can input commands under root

Comment: So you simply want to create a new user with sudo privileges ?

Comment: Exactly. Also, I would like to avoid those occasions when all data is being deleted once I reboot the system.\

Comment: Well I'll create an answer on how to create a new user with sudo privileges if that's what you want

Comment: Are you sure it isn't something really simple like the UID for the default non-guest account being too low to show up in the lightdm login screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a user with sudo permissions first type

```
sudo adduser username
```

Then enter your password. Then you'll be asked for some information, it's up to you whether you enter them or leave them empty. Once added, you have to add that user to the sudo group by typing

```
usermod -aG sudo username
```

Now username should be a new account with sudo privileges.